# Will alcoholic acid solution with organic acids break down Bakuchiol and reduce it's biological effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I wish to use Bakuchiol in a solution of isoproply alcohol and water in the presence of glycolic acid (7%), citric acid (0.5%) and salicylic acid (1.4%) at a pH of 4 to 5, adjusted with TEA.    Wu et al ("Synthesis and Evaluation of Bakuchiol Derivatives as potential Anticancer Agents") claim that Bakuchiol reacts with water or methanol at room temperature in the presence of 'dilute' H2SO4 to form an ether or alcohol from the terminal alkene.   So will my weaker organic acids break down the Bakuchiol terminal alkene by this pathway to either an alcohol or ether (with aq IPA) ?  Or are the organic acids too weak and having too strong a nucleaphilic counter ion to react this way.  Standard theory for ether formation from alkanes requires a strong acid with a poor nucleophilic counter ion .. but Bakuchiol is branched and kind of conjugated, so the terminal alkene may be more reactive.   Can you advise ?  Proceed ?   How do I test for no reaction at home ?  Colour ?

Comment: At pH 4-5 I doubt it

Comment: Thank you Waylander